# SASS/Compass: Inherit from mixin

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs4.1, compass-sass, mixins

In Ext JS 4, they added a way to override the default coloring scheme by using SASS/Compass, so what I'm trying to do is create a new button style, using `extjs-button-ui`, and then applying that style to a button.  The button's code is as follows:

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'should be orange',
ui: 'orange'
```

My SASS code is as follows:

```
$button-default-background-color: mix(blue, red);
$orange-button-background-color: mix(yellow, red);
@import 'compass';
@import 'ext4/default/all';

@include extjs-button-ui(
  'orange',
  $button-small-border-radius,
  $button-small-border-width,

  $button-default-border-color,
  $button-default-border-color-over,
  $button-default-border-color-focus,
  $button-default-border-color-pressed,
  $button-default-border-color-disabled,

  $button-small-padding,
  $button-small-text-padding,

  $orange-button-background-color,
  $button-default-background-color-over,
  $button-default-background-color-focus,
  $button-default-background-color-pressed,
  $button-default-background-color-disabled,

  $button-default-background-gradient,
  $button-default-background-gradient-over,
  $button-default-background-gradient-focus,
  $button-default-background-gradient-pressed,
  $button-default-background-gradient-disabled,

  $button-default-color,
  $button-default-color-over,
  $button-default-color-focus,
  $button-default-color-pressed,
  $button-default-color-disabled,

  $button-small-font-size,
  $button-small-font-size-over,
  $button-small-font-size-focus,
  $button-small-font-size-pressed,
  $button-small-font-size-disabled,

  $button-small-font-weight,
  $button-small-font-weight-over,
  $button-small-font-weight-focus,
  $button-small-font-weight-pressed,
  $button-small-font-weight-disabled,

  $button-small-font-family,
  $button-small-font-family-over,
  $button-small-font-family-focus,
  $button-small-font-family-pressed,
  $button-small-font-family-disabled,

  $button-small-icon-size
);
```

I have a couple of questions/observations.  When I compile this, I get no errors and the standard Ext JS theme with purple buttons, but the button I defined above, has no style... it's just text.  These variables are all included in the **_all.scss** file, which imports the **_variables.scss** file, which includes the variable definitions that are in **variables/_button.scss**, and if the vars were undefined, the compiler would whine.

My first question is, why is this not working/what am I missing?

And my second, more broad SASS question, how do I inherit from a mixin?  The **orange** include is actually inheriting all of those variables from the **default-small** extjs-button-ui.  So I want the background-color and name to be orange, but I want everything else to be inherited from the **default-small** include.  Is this possible?  I thought something like:

```
@include extjs-button-ui(
  @include extjs-button-ui('default-small'),
  'orange',
  $button-default-background-color: mix(yellow, red)
}
```

would be the ticket, but I was apparently horribly wrong.  I can inherit a mixin by doing something like:

```
.orange {
  @include extjs-button-ui('default-small', $icon-size: 16px);
  $button-default-background-color: mix(yellow, red);
}
```

But that's not creating an orange ui that I can use in Ext JS... just an orange CSS class that has the button values, but not my background-color.  So what am I doing wrong?  I've tried looking all over for ways to accomplish this, but nothing's working.  Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: It's good to note that I've tried messing around with `@extend` as well but had no probability.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide the source for the `extjs-button-ui` mixin?

Comment: Yeah sure... I copied this out of the widgets/_button.scss file... [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/qy0ZMEKL).

Comment: Also, if you'd like to view the other files in there, you can have a peak [on GitHub](https://github.com/probonogeek/extjs/tree/master/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default).

Comment: Without a greater understanding of the design behind this library, I can only tell you that the mixin is designed in a way that it generates all of the selectors necessary to create that component.  If you want to use extend (which will give you a more compact CSS file), you'll have to find out what the class name is for the default-small class (something like `x-btn-default-toolbar-small` if using the default settings), then start overriding whatever you need.

Comment: Ah, so there isn't an easy way of inheriting (using the `extjs-button-ui` mixin with `default-small`) and just overriding from there?  By overriding the actual generated class name, that doesn't seem like the SASS way... I should be able to instantiate a new ui class with default values.  I'll keep looking.  Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Something like `.orange { @extend .x-btn-default-toolbar-small; background: mix(yellow, red); }` *could* potentially work.  The design of the button mixin looks FUBAR in my opinion:  too much stuff being done by a single mixin.